# how to capture a specific substring from a variable's string value?(cmd or batch)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to escape some characters in a string. The string is constantly changing, for example `Set-Cookie: SESSION=60a8245bc1976b40d0d8c4ff6f9784fc; path=/`
I want to remove `Set-Cookie: SESSION=` and `; path=/` to leave `60a8245bc1976b40d0d8c4ff6f9784fc`.
But since it has "complex" characters, like `:` `=` `/` returns an error when i try

```
SET cookies2=%cookies:Set-Cookie: SESSION=%
SET cookies3=%cookies2:; path=/=%
echo %cookies3%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `for /f` loop to split the string:

```
@echo off
set "string=Set-Cookie: SESSION=60a8245bc1976b40d0d8c4ff6f9784fc; path=/"
set string
for /f "tokens=2 delims==;" %%a in ("%string%") do set "var=%%a"
echo -%var%-
```